# how can I store token and users auth at firestore..?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to store user's token and email, password at firestore.
If I put the code in js file and logged in, the firestore collection is gonna be created... right?

But I can get some messages from console...not firestore data.

in my console...there are messages,
1.'got the permission'
2. explaning about my serviceworker
3.'token'

this is part of my code.
firebase.init.js

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


const messaging = firebase.messaging();


const loginUser = ({
    email,
    password
}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        // dispatch action
        dispatch({
            type: LOGIN_USER
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('error occured.')
        });
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)     **changed
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            var user = userCredential.user;
            // ...
        })
        .catch((error1) => {
            var errorCode = error1.code;
            var errorMessage = error1.message;
            console.log(errorCode, errorMessage);
            // ..
        });
    };
};
messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('got the permission');
        // get the device's push token
        return messaging.getToken()
    })
    .then(function(token) {
        const { currentUser } = auth();
        token => {
            console.log(currentUser.email, currentUser.uid)
                .catch(function(error2) {
                console.log('error2 occured.')
            });
            // store token in the user's document
            db.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid)
                .set({
                    pushToken: token,
                    numFinds: 0,
                    numCares: 0
                })
                .catch(function(error3) {
                console.log('error3 occured.' );
            });
        };
        console.log(token);
    })
    .catch(function(error4) {
        console.log('error4 occured.');
    });
```

thanks your help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are not using properly the function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, please catch the error of the function as it might reveal the issue.

From [1]

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    var user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ..
  });
```

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account

Comment: Thanks your comment. I added code you wrote. And there are some change. in my console, "error4 occured." "got the permission" that's all. haha...... i don't no why it is, should do.

Comment: please include a screenshot of the error or the complete text in verbatim